# SQL Decimal Field Conversion to Binary

Tags: sql-server, decimal

I have a question: in SQL Server there is a `decimal` data type.

I can convert this datatype to binary, so I can write query as

```
declare @deci decimal(18,2)
set @deci = 2.33
print cast(@deci as varbinary)
```

The result of this query is --

```
0x12020001E9000000
```

My question is what is the conversion rule for this conversion from decimal to binary..can anybody explain to me?

Comment: What is the reason for the question? [See warning here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) "Do not try to construct binary values and then convert them to a data type of the numeric data type category. SQL Server does not guarantee that the result of a decimal or numeric data type conversion to binary will be the same between versions of SQL Server."

Comment: The result is sql-server's internal representation of 2.33 as a decimal (18,2). Why do you want it in binary. It's an internal format could end up being specific to dec(18,2) in that version of sql server. Exposing it seems, well risky.

Comment: The reson behind is..I need to fist convert data in binary format then encrypt it and then save it somewhere. I have done encryption on all ohter data types except decimal. And I dont think there is any security issue. It is simply IEEE754 standard to represent decimal filed but I am not able to convert it according to the specification.